# There is no datapoints when i apply aggregation method to my field in grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I am using influxdb as the backend of grafana, when I configure my metrics with the following query, everything works

```
SELECT "puller.request" 
FROM "api_puller" 
WHERE "hostname" = 'xxxxxxx' 
AND $timeFilter
```

This generates the following sql to influxdb

```
SELECT "puller.request" 
FROM "api_puller" 
WHERE "hostname" = 'xxxxxxx' 
AND time  now() - 5m
```

The problem arises when I want to get the `mean` of my metrics

```
SELECT mean("puller.request") 
FROM "api_puller" 
WHERE "hostname" = 'xxxxxxx' 
AND $timeFilter
```

The sql for this query is :

```
SELECT mean("puller.request") 
FROM "api_puller" 
WHERE "hostname" 'xxxxxxx' 
AND time > now() - 5m
```

There is no data points show on my dashboard.
I copied that `sql` to execute it directly in `influxdb`. `influxdb` indeed output some value. But `grafana` still cannot show any data point.

Is there something wrong with my query? or how should I make the `mean` function work?

### My `grafana` version is :   `Grafana v4.4.3 (commit: 54c79c5)`

Thanks in advance.